# IList rewriting itself

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

So what i'm doind for the moment is getting information from win32 classes and putting that information on my view using a viewmodel -> mvvm. So at this point i aquire information from my disks and put them on my view. Since for example my pc and server have pultiple drive I use a for each loop and add theinformation in a list -> I have tried IList<> and ICollection<>. my current code:

//disk
            int index = 0;

```
        ObjectQuery objectQuery3 = new ObjectQuery("select * from Win32_LogicalDisk");
        ManagementObjectSearcher searcher3 = new
        ManagementObjectSearcher(objectQuery3);
        ManagementObjectCollection disks = searcher3.Get();

        foreach (ManagementObject value in disks)
        {

            disk.FreeSpace = (Convert.ToUInt64(value.GetPropertyValue("FreeSpace"))/1024/1024/1024/1024);
            disk.Size = (Convert.ToUInt64(value.GetPropertyValue("Size")) /1024/1024/1024/1024);
            disk.Name = Convert.ToString(value.GetPropertyValue("Name"));
            disk.VolumeName = Convert.ToString(value.GetPropertyValue("VolumeName"));

            storage.Insert(index, disk);
            index++;
        }
```

My problem here when i put a breakpoint at the list is -> he gets the information from my first disks put's it in 'disk' model aka class. next he add's the model in the IList. next iteration he get information put's it into the model but after that he overwrites current ilist index 0 and then add itself on index 1. next iteration the same he overwrites index 0 overwrites index 1 and adds itself on index 2. leaving me exactly the same information every time from my last disk. Any ideas on how to fix this?

besides insert method I have tried add method too.

Comment: You use the same instance of disk within your foreach loop. You have to create a new instance of disk every iteration.

Comment: @sebastian siemens thank you that did it,